# Will windows applications run on ubuntu?

Tags: windows-8

If I switch to ubuntu from windows will my programs from windows still work on ubuntu? or will I have to download the ubuntu counterpart of the program?

Comment: What have you found yourself? This question has been asked *many* times here. Please use the search!

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwitchingToUbuntu/FromWindows

Answer (score 0):

It's aways better to use a native program.

But if you desire, you could try running your windows programs using Wine (See winehq.org) or through a virtual machine. The later has a mode which you can run your machines "like they were native". As in, without the virtual machine explicitly being displayed

Answer (score 0):

In general its usually best to try and find an Ubuntu or at least Linux equivalent of any program you want rather than  try to run Windows applications.

In many cases you will find suitable software for free in the software centre.

For those cases where this is not possible there is a compatibility layer called [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/) which can be used to run some Windows programs but its less than perfect many programs run very well others are next to useless.  There is a [database](http://appdb.winehq.org/) to indicate how well many popular programs run.  You can install Wine from the software centre.

For Windows programs that don't run well under wine you also have the option of installing Windows inside a virtual machine such as [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) also available from the software centre but this requires a Windows licence and install media.

Finally if you really need a Windows machine you can dual boot Windows and Ubuntu switching between the two of them as necessary.